# ¿como obtener valores que están dentro de una de una db y convertirlos en un entero o string en web2py?

Tags: web2py

intento sacar los datos de una tabla de una base de datos y poder manipularlos en una función en el controlador de mi aplicación.
Si intento obtener los datos con un select, selecciona el campo, pero no el valor que esta dentro del campo.

en mi modelo tengo esta tabla

```
db.define_table('item',
    Field('Nombre','string')
    Field('imagen', 'upload'),
    Field('votos', 'integer', default=0))
```

y en mi controlador

```
def ejemplo():
    a = db(db.item.id==1).select(db.item.votos)
    return (a)
```

y en mi controlador desearía sumar lo que hay dentro del campo 'votos' del modelo a otra variable por ejemplo:

```
def ejemplo():
    a = db(db.item.id==1).select(db.item.votos)
    b = 20
    suma = a+b
    return (suma)
```

saludos.

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar __cómo__ obtienes los datos de tu tabla, __cómo__ los manipularíaas en Python y __cómo__ seleccionas el campo? Edita tu pregunta y usa el botón `{ } ` para darle formato a tu código.

Comment: ya modifique mi pregunta, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Es que estas tratando de sumar un `select` no te regresa el dato como tal si no un `array` de registros

Esto te debería funcionar

```
def ejemplo():
   a = db(db.item.id==1).select(db.item.votos)[0].votos
   b = 20
   suma = a+b
   return (suma)
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma sería:

```
def ejemplo():
    a = db(db.item.id==1).select(db.item.votos).first()
    b = 20
    if a != None:
        suma = a.votos+b
    else:
        suma = b
    return(suma)
```